# Retrieve data inside () with regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to retrieve a numeric value from a webpage using regex.

(I was not able to get simple_php_dom handling https requests.)

Here is the code containing the numeric value (**78**)

```
<p class="b45">
<a href="/?page=browseAllPages&amp;idCategory=1&amp;idUser=12345">
Display all tables (78)
</a></p>
```

Here is the command I use

```
preg_match_all("/Display all tables \((.*)\)/", $file_content, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0][0]);
```

but it returns

```
string(137) "

Display all tables (78)
"
```

**Edit:** my mistake

```
var_dump($matches[1][0]);
```

is correct, but then it returns

```
string(9) " (78)"
```

To Return the value

```
echo $matches[1][0];
```

:)

Comment: var_dump($matches[1][0]);

Comment: The documentation was clear.

Comment: yeah, but it would then return           string(9) " (78)" and not 78

Comment: `preg_match_all("/Display all tables \(([^)]*)\)/", $file_content, $matches);` would probably closer to what you want,  `[^)]` means anything but )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
preg_match_all('/Display all tables \((\d+)\)/', $file_content, $matches);
$mtch = (int)$matches[1][0];
var_dump($mtch);
```

Comment: it returns string(2) "78"

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOS
<p class="b45">
<a href="/?page=browseAllPages&amp;idCategory=1&amp;idUser=12345">
Display all tables (78)
</a></p>
EOS;

preg_match_all("/Display all tables \((.*)\)/", $string, $matches);

echo $matches[1][0] . " - " . gettype($matches[1][0]) . "\n";
echo (int)$matches[1][0] . " - " . gettype((int)$matches[1][0]) . "\n";
```

After all you're getting substring that matches your regex. Even if you do it like this:

```
preg_match_all("/Display all tables \((\d+)\)/", $string, $matches);
```

But you can cast it to integer though.